# How do you Access the iPhone Settings App?

Tags: ios

How do you access the iPhone Settings App? How do you set up your own options and how do you read the option setting status from swiftui. Is there some kind of list of standard options available?

I've checked several books I have and Apple documentation online without finding anything on the subject. Maybe at least point me to some documentation.

Comment: Your app cannot arbitrarily read from the user's Settings.

Comment: Do you mean iPhone Settings app or your app permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Managing settings is not UI related, so it really has nothing to do with SwiftUI.

That said, read up on `UserDefaults` and [Settings Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html).